# List of updated documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is there a way to update (or delete) many documents matching a certain criteria and get the list of IDs of actually updated/deleted documents (or some other fields of those documents)? I cannot simply query the documents matching my criteria beforehand because I need kinda atomicity for this operation. And I can't use findAndModify because it can only process one document at a time which is too slow because of round-trips. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB only supports atomic operations on a single document.
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations

The only way to do this is to do what you said you didn't one to:

First query the collection to find id's for our query:

```
db.things.find({"name":"john"}, {_id:1});
```

Then, use the same query to remove:

```
db.things.remove({"name":"john"}, {_id:1});
```

Not ideal, and not atomic, but it's as good as you're going to get in this scenario.

Comment: No, atomicity is very important to me. So it's better to cycle with findAndModify if there's no other solution... I mean that I have to be absolutely sure that I know exactly that returned IDs correspond to actually updated/removed documents. As you can see, I mean atomicity over read/update operation pairs and not over the whole bunch of updates.

Comment: If atomicity is really *that* important, then perhaps you're better off using an RDBMS. Different horses for different courses.